# IE browser not support if default value assign at time of function define at javascript

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I am doing a project with codeigniter and javascript. But when i want to define like

```
 function function_name(price = 0) or function function name(name = '')
```

at javascript, it is showing error in IE browser but in another browser not showing any error and project is running very well. Then how will i define default value at javascript at the time of define a function, so every browser will support?

Comment: Assign the default value on the first line of the function instead?

Comment: What IE version? ... that could make a BIG difference. Know that IE11 [does not have support](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/)

Answer (score 1):

RORO patterns

```
function function_name(params)
{
    if(!params.price)
        params.price = 0;
}
```

Call

```
function_name({ price : 1 })
function_name({});
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope the below snippet will give a better understanding on the problem.

I hope this will solve the issue.

```js
function foo(val) {
   if(val === undefined) {
      val = false;
   }
   console.log("initial value of variable val =>", val)
}
//it can be often shortened to something like:

function bar(name) {
  name = name || 'Bob';
  console.log("initial value of variable name =>", name)
}

//The above is true for ECMAScript <= 5. and also if you use chrome <49 there is issue.

//ES6 has proposed Default parameters. So the above could be re written as

function zoo(status = 'Checked') {
 console.log(" initial value of variable status =>", status)
}

foo();
bar();
zoo();
```